# Extract data from log file

Tags: text-processing, command-line, regular-expression

I'm trying to learn how to parse files using the Linux commands and tools. I'm always confused on how to best leverage grep/awk/sed.

Here is a specific use case.

I have a log file that contains the following strings:

```
Config Server received a Connection Establishment with an invalid public key, closing connection. Agent Identifier: SRV3 Socket IP: 192.168.2.6
Config Server received a Connection Establishment with an invalid public key, closing connection. Agent Identifier: TESTSRV4 Socket IP: 10.1.2.3
Config Server received a Connection Establishment with an invalid public key, closing connection. Agent Identifier: SRV1 Socket IP: 192.168.2.15
Config Server received a Connection Establishment with an invalid public key, closing connection. Agent Identifier: TESTSRV2 Socket IP: 10.1.2.4
```

My goal is to extract the host name that appears after "Agent Identifier" and the associated IP address for each line and export them to a txt file. What would be the best way of going about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***sed*** approach:

```
sed -n 's/.* Agent Identifier: \(.*\) Socket IP: \(.*\)/\1 \2/p' inputfile > host_list.txt
```

---

*host_list.txt* file contents(`cat host_list.txt`):

```
SRV3 192.168.2.6
TESTSRV4 10.1.2.3
SRV1 192.168.2.15
TESTSRV2 10.1.2.4
```

Comment: The sed approach might be better because there is additional data in the log file that doesn't conform to the strings that I posted in this thread. Using "Agent Identifier" as the common criteria will probably work. I will have to test.

Comment: Thanks @RomanPerekhrest. The sed approach works like a charm. Gives me a starting point to learn text processing further. I'm looking for a good resource with examples to get better using grep/sed/awk.

Comment: @Heisenberg, you're welcome. To learn awk - find the book "GAWK: Effective AWK Programming", for other tools - official documentation is good(it's also good for awk)

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
$ cat file.log | awk '{ print $16, $19 }'
```

And it will return a list like this:

```
SRV3 192.168.2.6
TESTSRV4 10.1.2.3
SRV1 192.168.2.15
TESTSRV2 10.1.2.4
```

---

You can redirect the output anywhere you like, for example, just add:

```
> hosts.text
```

to output your data to a file named *hosts.txt*

The above will clobber (replace) any content in the *hosts.txt* file. If you want to append your data to the end of your file use `>>` instead of `>`.

Comment: it is not necessary to use `cat file.log |`. Simply do `awk '{ print $16, $19 }' file.log`.